# Pushing JSON Data into an array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a PHP script which returns a JSON response like the below

```
[{"agencyID":"99999", "name":"john", "surname":"doe", "bookings":[{
     "ID":"54321", "transactions":[{"desc":"example text"}],
    }]
}]
```

MUST ADD - I HAVE MADE UP THIS JSON - JUST AN EXAMPLE.

How do i push all this information into a JavaScript array from AJAX success block?

I would like to be able to use the information later for example like this -`$('#div').append(array.desc);`

```
Content-Type    
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Could you provide the `Content-Type` returned from the server and the code of your Ajax call? Also, be careful, there is a trailing comma at the end of line 2 of the JSON you provided but there is no second element in the array.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returned AJAX array not being copied to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867284/returned-ajax-array-not-being-copied-to-array)

Comment: What do you expect `array.desc` to return when you have multiple agencies, each one having multiple bookings, each one having multiple transactions?

Comment: `"MUST ADD - I HAVE MADE UP THIS JSON - JUST AN EXAMPLE"` the format of the json is vital to this question, as is your answer to @trincot above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the jQuery `ajax` method, you can push the response from your PHP script into an array and use it later. Here's an example:

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/to/php/script.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var array = [];
        array.push(data);
        $('#foo').append(array);
    }
});
```